# how to prevent `NSURL` Connection into property list stopping on unexpected characters

Tags: php, ios, nsurlconnection, eof, property-list

I'm having trouble detecting improper characters in my data.  I'm using SimplePost to post data, `PHP` to **process** it, `MySQL` to **store** it, `PlistParser` to **prepare** the return from PHP, and `NSURLConnection` to receive the responses, as below.  I'm using this in several places in my apps, and everything is usually great.  Now my data is growing and I'm often getting errors.

SimplePost is using:

```
    NSString *escapedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)([dictionary objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:i]]),NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Here's my connection code:

```
//  connection to URL finished with Plist-formatted Questions data array returned from PHP
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString  *error;
    NSArray *array = (NSArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:0 errorDescription:&error];
    if( error ) {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error );
    return;
}
```

The errors are:

```
Unexpected character x at line 1
Encountered unexpected EOF
... and such
```

When I look at the SimplePost escapedString or at the PHP function's returned data directly, I can't see anything unusual.  I don't know what is causing the errors.

Is there more filtering I can do somewhere to prevent such errors?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I really don't know what's going on. I combined my connection calls in one post, doing all the work on the backend and just receiving one returned array of dictionaries. Works beautifully - sometimes. Sometimes, it chokes on errors, giving "Unexpected EOF" and "Unexpected character at Line 1" errors. I'm baffled!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using URLEncoding rather than escapeStrings? You are probably trying to feed a character like this "&" and it's messing up your code...

example: if "var2" was equal to this string "54&3er"
than this:
http://test.php?var1=jl5&var2=54&3er&var3=blah

Now you have a random key "3er" with no assigned valued...

Google "URLEncode"

Comment: Thanks, Albert, I'll keep looking into encoding strategies.  I've tried a few different CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes, but haven't noticed any performance differences.  How about the possibility that my dB is expecting a VARCHAR(256) but occasionally the iPhone app is sending and later retrieving a string longer than 256 characters?  What problems would that cause?

Comment: I would think that your database would strip the values if it were longer than 256 characters, have you manually checked to see what happened?